# How can I enlarge font-size on phone navigation screen?

Tags: android, google-maps, galaxy

On-screen information like miles, time remaining and ETA (Estimated Time of Arrival)  are too small to be readable on Google Maps (tested on Samsung Galaxy S9). This is a recent change [for the worse] that I have I discovered in Google Maps. Has anyone else experienced this issue or/and found a way to resolve it?

I tried adjusting application and phone system settings, but without any success.

I need to have ETA information that is accessibly-sized.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Clarification of issue (as interpreted)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score -1):

You may adjust the size of the labels of the map by following these steps:

> 1. On your Android phone or tablet, open the Settings app
> 2. Tap **Accessibility**. From here, you can:
>
>    **Change font size**: To make words larger, tap Font size, and then set your preferred letter size.
>
>    **Change display size**: To make items on your screen larger, tap Display size, and then set your preferred icon size.

You may also refer to this [link](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6396990?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en&oco=2) for more information

Comment: Are you working at Google as your profile suggests?